# How do I switch from swipe-up to tap in order to answer a call?

Tags: settings, calls

I have a UMX phone running Android 8.1 Oreo. For some reason, I can't always answer an incoming call by swiping up. I do it several times, and the little green circle moves up with my finger, but then back down again and the phone keeps ringing, and I miss the call. Then sometimes, it does work, and I swipe up once and I answer the call.

I can't figure out what is the problem if I'm doing something wrong sometimes, or if it is a glitch in the software or a screen sensitivity issue, I don't know.

Could it make a difference if my finger is cold or dry? Sometimes my hands are cold, sometimes dry, sometimes sweaty. Does it matter how much pressure I apply to the phone when I swipe up?

Is there a way to switch from swipe-up to tap in order to answer a call? I could not find anything in settings that had to do with answering a call.

Comment: Please mention your device name and android version. If you're using your stock dialer application, it doesn't have any glitches or touch issues as it is mostly bugless. Touch screen with wet/sweat hands, may create a less response with screen. It maybe due to this reason, evenif you answer the call, it will get back and continue ringing.

Comment: You can try other dialers from Play Store, but I don't recommend that, because those may have some security issues. If you're trying, you need to set that app as default from settings application.